# Blue bar, Location updates in background changes in iOS11

Tags: swift, core-location, ios11

As you already heard, in iOS11, an app that’s actively receiving continuous background updates will show a double-height blue bar, whether authorization is set to While Using or Always. It seems there is no way to remove the blue bar if the App is using background location App.

[Changes to location tracking in iOS 11](https://mackuba.eu/2017/07/13/changes-to-location-tracking-in-ios-11/)

I made a demo App, it did show blue bar when the app was using background location updates.
But I found a weird thing, that is if I specify **NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription** in plist, the Blue bar won't show any longer even the App is using background location updates.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

But seems everybody says there is no way to remove the blue bar while background location updates is working.
So I quite doubt of what I found. Is this a bug of iOS11?

Comment: did you find a way to remove blue bar when we put app in background ?

Comment: Hi @RahulVyas, There is no blue bar if you specify `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` permission in your plist.

Comment: Will these 2 only works in ios 9 and 10 as well ?

Comment: I have added only 2 entries in info.plist but I'm still getting the blue bar when app is in background

Comment: yes, it works in both iOS9 and iOS10. I uploaded my demo App to [Github](https://github.com/zhihuitang/Geo-demo), you can play a little bit.

Comment: I have added both the keys but still while using the app I'm getting the Blue Location bar in ios 11

Comment: There is no blue bar in my demo App. Have you tried it out?

Comment: yes I have tried and I can see blue bar in ios 11.2.5 iphone 5S device.

Comment: See screenshot here (https://i.imgur.com/kkte1yK.png)

Comment: Also app icon is missing

Comment: Make sure you select "always" when it asks for location permission. The App icon is default one since I didn't set the icon. I just tested it again,  there is no blue bar on my iPhone7p(11.2.5)

Comment: I know it doesn't appear when we select always. But in uber even if you select "while using the app" there is no blue bar. Also we cannot force user to select always. User can pick any of the two options. Just install Uber and observe the behavior.

Comment: When select "while using the App", I guess Uber is not using background location update. Otherwise there must be a blue bar.

Comment: I've tried that as well. I've stopped location manager when app goes in background and the blue bar disappear after a second. But in Uber I've never seen the blue bar.

Comment: @ Rahul Vyas. Did you solved blue bar issue ?
I am also trying to do as like in UBER but not getting solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ios11 official release Apple reversed course on its plan to require all apps to overtly notify users when accessing their location in the background. Under the modified rules, apps that users allow to persistently track their location will not have to show the blue bar.

https://www.google.se/amp/s/adexchanger.com/mobile/apple-backtracks-blue-bar-shame-location-based-apps-ios-11/amp/